# How to enable the semi-transparent mesh that indicates the walls of my room in SteamVR?

Tags: steam-vr

I looked up the [Knowledge Base page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6281-TOKV-4722) about how to set it up, but it describes a step where I manually designate the area boundaries, and yet I did not see such a step in the Room Setup configuration menu. How do I set up the play area boundaries?

Answer (score 2):

During Room Setup, you will have 2 options for the kind of room configuration you want to set up:  Room-Scale and Standing Only.

[image]

You will only get the option to designate room boundaries in the Room-Scale setup path. It seems that you can't designate walls if you choose the Standing Only path.